# git-ls-files: command not found

Tags: bash, git

I googled this command and it said it is provided via git-man, which I have installed.  Anybody having issues with this command not being found?

It appears based on `git-ls-files` manpage that we can use git ls-files.  However, this breaks existing tool.  Is there a workaround for this?

/usr/bin/git-ls-files

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
git ls-files $args
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git-ls-files` is a manual page on Ubuntu. A search with `apt-file search git-ls-files` confirmed it.

If you want to use `git-ls-files` instead of `git ls-files`, create a symlink for it:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/git /usr/local/bin/git-ls-files
```

Unless some other program depends on this name, I'd just use `git ls-files`, the only difference is the first separator, dash (`-`) vs a space ().

If you wish to create such an alias for each git command, run the below bash command:

```
for file in /usr/lib/git-core/*; do name=${file##*/}; [[ $name != git ]] && [ -x "$file" ] && sudo ln -s "$file" "/usr/local/bin/$name"; done
```

This will create the symlinks in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Works, you answered so fast I can't flag it as the answer.  The issue lies in the tool https://github.com/tsgates/git-emacs.  Thanks!

Comment: I just tested another approach and it seems that I can even make a symlink to get `git-ls-files` working.

Comment: Well I may go that route, it's looking for a diff-status too.  Thanks for posting that